# wget error: certificate owner does not match hostname

Tags: wget, ssl

`wget` command fails to download a file with error "The certificate's owner does not match hostname"

Full command output is show below:

```
wget --continue --directory-prefix=/download https://server.example.com/repo/software-1.0.rpm

Resolving server.example.com (server.example.com)... 10.77.66.27

Connecting to server.example.com (server.example.com)|10.77.66.27|:443... connected.

The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘server.example.com’
```

This is on a RedHat 8.6 system and the `trust list` command does not show any certificate for `server.example.com`. However there is an entry with `label: localhost`

- Where is wget command finding a certificate for the server? Why is this not shown in verbose output?
- How to print the contents of this certificate or delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is looking at the certificate returned by `server.example.com`, and apparently that certificate is misconfigured (it is not actually for `server.example.com`) or you are using the incorrect hostname. This doesn't have anything to do with a certificate stored on your local filesystem.

You can either fix the server, if it's something you control, or you can disable certificate validation with the `--no-check-certificate` option:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --continue --directory-prefix=/download \
  https://server.example.com/repo/software-1.0.rpm
```

Comment: This helped!. Inspecting the server's certificate using the command `openssl s_client -connect server.example.com:443` revealed that the CN name in the certificate was wrong. Thanks!